# KeyClock authorization for backend APIs

Tags: node.js, api, authorization, keycloak

I am new to using KeyCloak for an application. There are less resources on the internet. My back-end is written in Node.js and there are many endpoints. Now I want to use KeyCloak to add authorization on my APIs. Like specific user roles can access specific routes of the API. How can I achieve this? Is this achievable?

I have looked for specific articles and checked out the docs of KeyCloak but couldn't find a good document or a web page for guidance.